# No errors but celery task not sending email as expected

Tags: docker, flask, redis, celery

I am trying to learn how to perform asynchronous tasks using Celery.

My app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from celery import Celery
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.getenv('MAIL_USERNAME', default='')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.getenv('MAIL_PASSWORD', default='')
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = os.getenv('MAIL_USERNAME', default='')
app.config['MAIL_SUPPRESS_SEND'] = False
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])

mail = Mail(app)

@celery.task
def send_celery_email(message_data):
    with app.app_context():
        message = Message(subject=message_data['subject'], recipients= [message_data['recipients']], body= message_data['body'])
        mail.send(message)

@celery.task
def hello():
    print('Hello')


class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('email')



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        message_data = {
            'subject': 'Hi from Flask app',
            'recipients': email,
            'body': 'This is an email sent from the flask app' 
        }
           
        
        send_celery_email.delay(message_data)
        hello.delay()


        return 'Email sent!'
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run()
```

my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
```

I have done the following:

1. Opened up a powershell terminal with my virtual environment and ran a redis server in docker

```
(env) PS C:\projects-directory\simpleceleryproj> docker-compose up -d
```

I checked that the server was up and running using the telnet command. When the blank screen appeared i typed "PING" and it returned "PONG".

```
(env) PS C:\projects-directory\simpleceleryproj> telnet localhost 6379
```

2. Opened another powershell terminal with my virtual environment active and started the celery worker

```
(env) PS C:\projects-directory\simpleceleryproj> celery -A app.celery worker
```

This is what appears on the screen:

```
(env) PS C:\projects-directory\simpleceleryproj> celery -A app.celery worker
 
 -------------- celery@LAPTOP-MKMU5ESC v5.0.5 (singularity)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 2021-04-08 10:42:51
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         app:0x35dac28
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

I then started the flask app, filled in the form and submitted it.

I get redirected to the 'Email sent!' page, but nothing actually happens. I dont receive an email in my inbox as I should.

I know the code is working because when I call the celery task function on its own directly I get an email as expected:

```
send_celery_email(message_data)
```

I really don't know why it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Upate:
I ran the celery worker with logging enabled and see the following output:

```
[2021-04-08 11:31:55,080: INFO/MainProcess] celery@LAPTOP-MKMU5ESC ready.
[2021-04-08 11:32:10,707: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.send_celery_email[3798423c-eff9-4b9f-9024-550e905d167b]
[2021-04-08 11:32:10,714: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.hello[46dc45bb-603d-48ce-af35-62d99c523db2]
[2021-04-08 11:32:11,392: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process 18348 calling self.run()
[2021-04-08 11:32:11,392: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 9472 calling self.run()
[2021-04-08 11:32:11,397: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process 16932 calling self.run()
[2021-04-08 11:32:11,404: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process 17932 calling self.run()
[2021-04-08 11:32:12,993: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-13] child process 13416 calling self.run()
[2021-04-08 11:32:12,993: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-14] child process 5680 calling self.run()
[2021-04-08 11:32:13,022: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process 17024 calling self.run()
[2021-04-08 11:32:14,586: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-16] child process 6484 calling self.run()
```

So celery actually does receive the tasks, it just doesnt execute them and I cant understand why.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by calling the worker with this command:

celery -A app.celery worker --pool=solo --loglevel=info

For more info on this:
https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/